# Dynamically filter text displayed based on user input

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a tool to take a formatted text file that stores our logging information and returns only certain parts of it. For example the log file looks something like this:

```
[TimeStamp] <Config>: Configuration note is shown here
[TimeStamp] <Info>: Information is written here   
[TimeStamp] <Info>: More Information
[TimeStamp] <Step>: A generated step is writing a message
[TimeStamp] <Warning>: A warning is logged
[TimeStamp] <Error>: An error has occurred
```

I would like to take this text from the file, and based on checkboxes for each log message type in the angle brackets, the user can hide what they don't care to see. Such as unchecking the 'Step' checkbox would hide the Step line, but if they were to recheck it, it would reappear in the text window.

I tried storing each line into a string which is stored in a list to keep each line in order, however this method is very very slow at changing the text. The method is shown below

```
logTextbox.Text = "";
foreach (string line in CompleteLog) //CompleteLog is list containing each line in log file
{
   if (CheckLine(line)) //Checks line based on what the user wants to see
   {
      WriteLine(line);
   }
}
```

Any suggestions would be very welcome

Edit:

```
        private bool CheckLine(string line)
    {
        int left = line.IndexOf('<');
        int right = line.IndexOf(">:");

        string logtype = line.Substring(left+1, right - left-1);
        if (ValidLogs.Any(p => p.ToLower().Equals(logtype.ToLower())))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

ValidLogs is a list of strings that contain what is allowed that is setup on load, and changed on a check event for the checkboxes corresponding to the log type. The 1st method above is used on load and each check event to update what is displayed.

Comment: How many lines do you have in your log file? And which graphic framework are you using?

Comment: Also, how exactly is CheckLine implemented? That seems to me like it could be part of the problem.

Comment: What are using to display the lines? I can think of few ways to improve the matching, but this looks more like UI issue

Comment: I am just using Windows Form (just for ease of setting up), and I am just using the RichTextbox tool, which i am sure is not very effecient, but I didn't think it would be so bad..

Comment: Oh, and the files can be very long and vary. Anywhere between hundreds to maybe a few thousand lines

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this would be to use a listview control. You could add an item per line in the text file and then filter the items (rows) that are displayed depending on the checkboxes. May I recommend [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) as a way of achieving this and making it look beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have memory limitations or excessively large files and your filter criteria are fixed you could pre-parse each line for the filter criteria and store the filter details on a log object you'd then have objects with simple properties to check rather having to re-parse everytime.

```
public class LogLine {
       public string Text { get; set; }
       public eLogLevel LogLevel { get; set; }
       // other filter properties
}
```

Then you would change your CheckLines() to filter the list of LogLine objects.

```
logTextbox.Text = "";
foreach (LogLine line in ParsedLog) //ParsedLog is list containing each line in log file pre-parsed
{
   if (CheckLine(line)) //Checks line based on what the user wants to see
   {
      WriteLine(line.Text);
   }
}
```